# Google Assistant DialogFlow for Workout?

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I'm making a simple assistant with no interaction other than the kickoff command words. Once it starts, I would like it to say various phrases after some amount of time.

I'm currently attempting this with DialogFlow Fulfillment with some `setTimeout()` calls, however it doesn't kick off the routine.

1. Can I use `setTimeout()` for this? If not, what do I use to space the statements out
2. How do I kick off the routine using Fulfillment?

Ideal flow

- I say: "Hey Google, start Awesome Workout"
- Google says: "Starting Awesome Workout"
- Google says: "Jumping Jacks, go"
- After 30 seconds, Google says: "Break"
- After 15 seconds, Google says: "Push ups, go"
- Repeat break and different exercise a few more times

Answer (score 2):

It seems like in the fulfillment, you have to use an SSML tag. Use `<break time=30</>` for 30 second break or 15 second break.

Please refer the link for SSML in fulfillment:- https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml

Answer (score 0):

Actions on Google and Dialogflow are conversational - most interaction is the user saying something, AoG/Dialogflow replying, and this process repeating. You can't use `setTimeout()` on the server, since the reply will already have been sent.

Your replies can include [SSML markup](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml) to do the breaks you want, but your reply is still limited by overall length (about 2 minutes), and probably much shorter than the routine you're looking to do.

A better approach will be to do things that use a [Media Response](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses). This lets you send some text, followed by mp3 audio. When the audio is finished, it will send a message back to your server and you can send the next instruction (and audio). The downside to this is that the timing will not be precise - you can control the length of what you say and how long the audio is, but there will be some lag with the network round trip.